# Generators are called more than expected in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I found a behavior where the generator appears to be called twice.

The following is a simple code that gets a number from the generator and output it to console.
It expects 0 and 1 to be output to the console, but in fact it outputs 0 and 2.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
 
function* counter() {
  let val = 0;
  while (true) yield val++;
}
const count = counter();

function App() {
  console.log("rendered: count = ", count.next().value);
  const [hoge, setHoge] = useState("first");
  console.log("rendered:", hoge);

  useEffect(() => setHoge("second"), [setHoge]);
  return <div>{hoge}</div>;
}

export default App;
```

demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-http-g84cp?file=/src/App.tsx

Not only to `useEffect`, I also found the same behavior with `setInterval`. Also, if we remove <React.strict>, the console outputs 0 and 1 as expected.

Do you have any idea why this behavior is happening?

Comment: why did you put `setHoge` in dependency array of `useEffect` ? it should be `hoge`

Comment: Wouldn't that cause infinite updates, since every time the hoge is updated, the useEffect updates the hoge?

Comment: no that wouldn't cause infinite updates. `useEffect` checks the state variable not state updater function(`setHoge`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html),

**Strict mode** can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic. This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:

- Class component constructor, render, and shouldComponentUpdate methods
- Class component static getDerivedStateFromProps method
- Function component bodies
- State updater functions (the first argument to setState)
- Functions passed to useState, useMemo, or useReducer

That **Function component bodies** being invoked twice is the cause of your problem. That means on initial mount, `App` function body will be invoked twice and then again on setting a new state, `App` function body will be invoked twice. By that logic, you should have seen 4 more logs i.e 8 in total.

Here is where the following exception comes :-

> Starting with React 17, React automatically modifies the console
> methods like console.log() to silence the logs in the second call to
> lifecycle functions. However, it may cause undesired behavior in
> certain cases where a workaround can be used.

To actually visualize all the 8 logs, you can just do `let log = console.log` at the top level and replace usage of `console.log` by `log` and you will see what's actually happening.

**Simply said**, don't put such a behavior inside a **function body** since it's a side-effect for which **Strict-mode** came into being.

Here is a forked codesandbox to see this :-

[image: Edit dreamy-aryabhata-ddzyz]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I now understand the cause: Strict mode is deliberately reading the application twice to detect side effects. That's pretty interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The [`<React.StrictMode>`](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper) exists to detect precisely what you're doing in your code which is an anti-pattern (side-effect in the render function).

This mode executes the lifecycle methods of the components twice on purpose (in your case it's a functional component so the function is being executed twice), while swallowing the `console.log` by [monkeypatching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) it.

That's why you observe the generator increment without any log in the console.

Comment: The side effects are caused by the implementation of the counter as a generator.  I didn't notice it, though it is obvious now. Thank you very much!